Find Basis and dimension for the subspace
Determine the basis and dimensions of the following vector space :
$$1. \ V = \left\{  \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ -b \\ a \end{pmatrix} \right\} $$
I'm confused about how to solve this,
Can the span of $V$ be written as a linear combination of : (if it uses this, then the dimension is 2?)
$$= s. \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ -b \\ a \end{pmatrix}+t. \begin{pmatrix} c \\ d \\ -d \\ c \end{pmatrix} $$
or it's just :(if it uses this, then the dimension is 1?)
$$= s. \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ -b \\ a \end{pmatrix}$$
Thank you

It looks like you're considering $a$ and $b$ as constants; but I think a more likely interpretation of the notation is that $a$ and $b$ are parameters that are free to run over all real numbers. (It could have been written more clearly IMO.)

@GregMartin yes, i got confused because there are no constants.

Your vector space is $$\ V = \left\{  \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ -b \\ a \end{pmatrix} : a,b \in \Bbb R \right \} $$
Observe that $\begin{pmatrix} a \\ b \\ -b \\ a \end{pmatrix} = a\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + b \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$. Also $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ are linearly independent vector. So, it is a basis of $V$. Hence $\dim V = 2$.
As OP doesn't specify anything about $a,b$, an update has to be given.
Note that

if $a = b = 0$ then $V = \{0\}.$
if $a \neq 0, b =0$ then $\ V = \left\{  a\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} : a \in \Bbb R \right \}$, basis is $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\dim V = 1$.
if $b \neq 0, a =0$ then $\ V = \left\{  b\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} : a \in \Bbb R \right \}$, basis is $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\dim V = 1$.
if $a \neq 0, b \neq 0$ then $\ V = \left\{  a\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} + b \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} : a,b \in \Bbb R \right \}$, basis is $\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} , \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 1 \\ -1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}\}$ and $\dim V = 2$.


So the solutions is $$a=b=0$$ right?

It is unclear from your question, but if you assume $a=b=0$, then it is a zero vector space. If one of them is non-zero, it will give you a one-dimensional vector space, and if both $a,b$ are non-zero, then a two-dimensional vector space.

The notation is a little ambiguous, I agree. A less ambiguous way of describing this set is:
$$V_1=\{ v \;| \; \exists \; a,b \mbox{ such that }\; v_1=v_4=a \mbox{ and } v_2=-v_3=b\}$$
You could also say, “$V_1$ is the set of all vectors of the following form:”
Anyway, if you plug in some values for $a,b,c,d$ you should (usually) get a basis (besides if you plug in a clearly dependent set). Thus, you are right, the dimension is $2$.
For example, $(1,0,0,1), (0,1,-1,0)$ is a basis.

The first two sentences are helpful (and the last sentence is accurate), but this answer would be improved by changing the third sentence into an explicit justification that the dimension is indeed $2$ (there is a natural basis to point out, given the form of the set).

@GregMartin Okay! I wanted to leave the explicit construction of a basis to the OP since it seemed they were on the right track. I added a sentence, thank you.
